# Get active threads in a discord channel (Discord.py / Pycord)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am having an issue fetching active threads on a discord channel. There is not much info about it, or maybe I just couldn't find it. So maybe it's not even possible idk

My code:

```
import discord
from tools.config import TOKEN

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")

@bot.slash_command(name="chat", description="some desc")
async def chat(ctx, msg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    user_name = ctx.author
    await ctx.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
    thread = await channel.create_thread(name=f"Thread was created {user_name}", type=None)
    await thread.send("Message in a thread")

    await ctx.respond(f'Some message with tagging after creating a thread. {user_name.mention}')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

What I am trying to implement is this:
user executes slash command, then the bot creates a thread where all the communications with the user are done in, but before creating a thread bot needs to verify that the user is not in any active threads in the current channel. To do that, I need to fetch active threads in the current channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're using Discord.py 2.0+, there is important changes and features that only exist on newest versions.

I think I found a way to solve your problem. First get all threads from channel using `channel.threads`, if I understood well the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.threads) this already get not archived threads (which means they're still active), then check if your user is between the members of threads.

```py
async def user_has_no_thread(ctx):
    threads = ctx.channel.threads
    if none(ctx.author in thread.members for thread in threads):
        return True
    return False
```

you can also define a faster `auto_archive_duration` when use `channel.create_thread()` to make sure they will be archived soon, by default is around 3 days I guess. Take a look [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_thread) if you want know more about the function.

Also make sure you have enable members intents for this works

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```